# Convert object into parameters for function

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, parameters

I have a AJAX with php that outputs different functions to run on the jquery side of things.

```
$.each(data['function'],function(key,value){
  window[key](value)
}
```

`data['function']` contains function data to run.

For example:

```
{"append":{"message":"hello","url":"link.com"}}
```

Will activate function

```
function append(message,url){...}
```

The problem is that `{"message":"hello","url":"link.com"}` is all contained in `message`. How can I translate or convert `{"message":"hello","url":"link.com"}` as parameters for the function?

right now it's running like this:

```
append({"message":"hello","url":"link.com"},undefined)
```

What is the solution to enable it to run like this:

```
append("hello","link.com")
```

I want to keep parameters intact `append(message,url)` and not resort to a single parameter method. I can't quite find a good solution.

### Edited (Simplified)

How can I change Params object:

```
var Params={"message":"hello","url":"link.com"}
window['append'](Params);
```

To run the same as:

```
window['append']("hello","link.com")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spread the values of the `data['function']` object into the parameter list of the function you want to call:

```
append(...Object.values(data.function.message));
```

The old way to do it would be to use `.apply` instead:

```
append.apply(undefined, Object.values(data.function.message));
```

Note that it's pretty confusing to have an *object* inside a key named `function` - one would probably expect a function to be there instead. You might consider a different property name, such as `parametersObj` or something of the sort.

If the function name is dynamic as well (which is a code smell), then use `Object.entries` to get both the key (function name) and value (object) at once:

```
const [fnName, obj] = Object.entries(data.function);
window[fnName](...Object.values(obj));
```

Comment: The ajax php give me data like {"function":{"append":{"element":"test","url":"test"}}} which is outputted as json data. Which I want to use to call the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your method but it just gives me a comma separated string for message and url is still undefined.

Comment: Oh, it's the `.message` property that has the object whose values you're looking for, see edit

Comment: I need the object values Message and Url to correspond to the function Append parameters(Message,Url)

Comment: I added an edit. Maybe it can explain it a bit better! Thanks

Comment: The edit should do it, use `Object.entries` to get both the function name and the object at once, and then you can call the appropriate function on `window` with the values of the object

Comment: Doesn't work. Message gives me "hello,link.com" and Url is still undefined. object.values just gives me back a comma separated string for Message.

Comment: My apologies, it worked. I never knew I needed the "...". What is the "...". O__O

Comment: That's spread syntax - in this case, it converts an array into part of an argument list.